# Colored operads encode 1-colored operads

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, reference-request, category-theory, operads

In their paper [BOUSFIELD LOCALIZATION AND ALGEBRAS OVER COLORED OPERADS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.06720.pdf#page54) David White and Donald Yau, write:

> Colored operads encode even more general algebraic structures, inluding the category of operads itself.

I suppose that means that there is a colored operad whose category of algebras is equivalent to the category of 1-colored operads. Where can I found a proof of this proposition?